# Geofence methods (Region Monitoring) not getting called while updating locations (Enter and Exit in Region)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have created a sample application for tracking GPS locations based on geofencing. First of all I have created one geofence and added the same to monitoring, using same location placed a circular overlay on MapView.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(23.518192, 72.337122);
CLCircularRegion *region1 =[[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centerCoordinate1 radius:100 identifier:@"Location First"];
NSLog(@"%@",[region1 description]);
region1.notifyOnEntry=YES;
region1.notifyOnExit=YES;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region1];
NSLog(@"Started Monitoring- %@", [region1 description]);
[self.mapview setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
// create circle around monitor region and check if worker location is changed
MKCircle *circle1 = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:centerCoordinate1 radius:100];
[self.mapview addOverlay:circle1];
```

Now, I am testing different co-ordinates in simulator by changing the simulator location by `Debug->Location->Custom Locations`.

If I am change major lat-long then it will call the region enter/exit methods, but if I am checking with near by locations by `+/-` with `10 or 20` points in latitude and longitude repetatively.

[First Image which is inside the GeoFence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcVyc.png)

[Another Image which is outside the GeoFence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PECKD.png)

Another image is visually outside the GeoFence, but while setting up this latitude and longitude it does not call `region exit` method.

Below are the region monitoring methods

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region;    
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

I am adding 4 to 5 regions to monitor at the same time.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested the same thing in real device? Probably there are possibility that your device works fine rather than simulator.

Comment: You need to wait some time before you will get a region exit  also depending on how large the region is, you may need to be a significant distance outside the region (100m or more) before the region exit fires

Comment: @Paulw11 all region's radius is 100m not more. i am waiting for 3 to 4 minutes.

Comment: it also depends on whether the user is moving or not. For example, I have found that using the "freeway drive" simulated location causes a pretty quick region exit notification, presumably because the high speed gives a pretty good indication that the user isn't about to re-enter the region. A static location just outside the region may take longer for the system to determine what is happening.  You can see in your second image that the blue shaded position overlaps the region, so the user could still be inside the region when positional accuracy is considered

Comment: @Merry Looks like this code is pretty good, there should be some modifications in testing. And how do you notify the user that you have just entered/exited the region?

Comment: @Paulw11 the Blue circle is just for showing the accuracy of your current location, if it's larger then it would be something around `100 or 200 meters` Plus/Minus. And if it's smaller then the accuracy is high, nearby around `10 to 50 meters`.

Comment: I already test with device. But, its not properly working for small distance. it's work properly long distance. While checking into simulator, If i change custom lat/long in **small range** then if current location set in or outside the region , that time notification not fire. But if i set custom lat/long in **high range** it's fire notification properly.

Comment: You can have a look at my region demonstration app - https://bitbucket.org/paulw11/locationtest  It only allows you to define a single region but it reliably detects region entry exits

Comment: @Paulw11 My code is working properly for single region. Somehow multiple regions are not working properly. Sometimes multiple times methods getting called of region enter/exit even if I am not entered/exited one region at a time.

Comment: I have updated my sample to handle multiple regions.