# How to Add the geofence of a region to monitoring.

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, mapkit, geofencing

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager

     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    // If it's a relatively recent event, turn off updates to save power
    NSLog(@"%@ locations",locations);

    float Lat = _locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
    float Long = _locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Lat : %f  Long : %f",Lat,Long);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.52171,77.2015457);

    NSLog(@"center check %@",center);
    CLCircularRegion *region = [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:center
                                                                 radius:500
                                                             identifier:@"new region"];
    BOOL doesItContainMyPoint = [region containsCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Lat,Long)];

    NSLog(@"success %hhd", doesItContainMyPoint);

}
```

the issue is ,here i m providing a static region for which i m checking (center)
but the requirement is, this region will take the lat n long of the riders and riders can vary in number

i hv all lat n long in an array of dictionary. First the driver will pick the first rider in the list and at that time i need the region of rider 1 location.
I m not getting any idea how to achieve this

if i do like this

```
for (NsMutableDictionary * dict in goersList)
    {
        rider_id=[dict valueForKey:@"trip_id"];
        lat=[dict valueForKey:@"origin_lat"];
        longi=[dict valueForKey:@"origin_long"];

}
```

then how will it know that the first region is to be monitored and after existing from that range i hv to check for second location

Comment: You need to add dynamically regions and monitoring that regions, Also you need to remove the regions at runtime. Please go through [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807060/region-monitoring-method-getting-called-multiple-times-in-geo-fencing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create dynamically regions and add them to monitoring.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [result valueForKey:@"Geofences"])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",dict);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[dict valueForKey:@"cLatitude"]doubleValue], [[dict valueForKey:@"cLongitude"]doubleValue]);

    CLCircularRegion *circularRegion=[[CLCircularRegion alloc]initWithCenter:locationCoordinate radius:[[dict valueForKey:@"Radius"]doubleValue] identifier:[dict valueForKey:@"Name"]];

    circularRegion.notifyOnEntry=YES;
    circularRegion.notifyOnExit=YES;
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:circularRegion];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] locationManager].monitoredRegions description]);
}
```

Here there are several regions are added to monitoring. You can add single at a time. i.e on selection of tableview.

And remove others using below code

```
for (CLRegion *monitored in [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].locationManager monitoredRegions])
{
    [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate].locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:monitored];
}
```

Comment: what is [result valueForKey:@"Geofences"] here @Vatsal K

Comment: @pooja_1205 It is the array which contains all geofences.

Comment: i have seen the link u mentioned above,even my requirement is almost the same.So have have completed this task

Comment: @pooja_1205 Thanks. All the best:)

Comment: i need a little more help from you @Vatsal K

Comment: @pooja_1205 Yes, what you want help from me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111439/discussion-between-vatsal-k-and-pooja-1205).